# how to handle close button of window in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, window

I am developing cocoa application having multiple windows. There is a red close button on left corner of window. And I want to handle click event of close button so that I can show message to ask user whether he wants to close window or not. If user accept to close window then application will be terminated otherwise same window shown to user.
Any idea how can I handle click event of close button???

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please look at [NSWindowDelegate protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), the method which you are looking for is-

```
- (BOOL)windowShouldClose:(id)sender
```

Comment: Can be worth noting that you will need to assign the class to be the windows delegate in order to handle the methods in NSWindowDelegate. :-)

Comment: Awesome. I actually used the `- (void)windowWillClose:(id)sender` API delegate instead for my case.

Answer (score 0):

NSWindowController has a method

```
- (BOOL)shouldCloseDocument
```

Comment: This is a property that signals whether or not window should close an associated NSDocument instance.